# Axios setting request headers differently in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: reactjs, firefox, axios, cors

I have a React app that connects to the backend through axios, the request configuration is set up like so:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    config.headers = Object.assign({
         Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
     }, config.headers);
    return config;}
)
```

This works just fine in Chrome, but in Firefox trying to make a call to the login endpoint yields this:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:5001/api/Account/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

Looking at the request headers in each browser, the only difference is in the `Sec-Fetch-Site` header, which is set to `cross-site` in Chrome but `same-site` in Firefox. Has anyone encountered this issue before? And is there some configuration in Axios that can ensure that requests will be "cross-site"?

I tried setting the `Sec-Fetch-Site` header directly in the configuration like so:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    config.headers = Object.assign({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site"
    }, config.headers);
    return config;
  }
)
```

But this doesn't work and gives this console message:

```
Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Sec-Fetch-Site
```

Is there another configuration that can make sure that the request headers are set up correctly? Or otherwise some way of manually setting the `Sec-Fetch-Site` header?